# How to get user's current location and send to server in iOS application when app is not running i.e. killed or suspended?

Tags: ios, swift, location

I need user's location and need to send it to server in every stage of app, i.e.

1. Foreground
2. Background
3. Suspend/Killed

What should be a best possible ways to achieve this?

Comment: 1) Foreground possible (Location manager) 2 ) Background Possible (Location manager with Background capability enabled) 3) Killed Not possible

Comment: Simply not possible (i.e. killed or suspended?)

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya thanks for comment, 
Do you know how google map manage this things in iOS app? 
I mean i got notification on everyday for the same like "Your home away from 6 Km" at the work end time? 
Is it possible to do this as well?

Comment: I don't know exactly how they able to manage it but you can use silent push notification to run your app for some seconds while killed. But again I am not sure it will allow to get user location or not. But you can defiantly  try this

Comment: Yes i understand the silent push notification, but that is only dependent on Location based.